# Redirecting directories to subdomains using Cloudflare.com?

Tags: dns, openshift, cloudflare

At the moment I have user directories accessible like the following

```
    mydomain.com/files/user1/
```

but I would like it so the users can simply type in the browser

```
    user1.mydomain.com
```

How do I set this up on Cloudflare to work automatically? I know it has to do with subdomain wildcard forwarding, but I'm not sure how to accomplish it on Cloudflare or Openshift....

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I think this would be one option:

- in CloudFlare > DNS add an A new record for `user1.example.com` that points to the appropriate IP
- in Cloudflare > Page rules add a new rule for pattern: `http://user1.example.com/*` that forwards to `http://example.com/files/user1/$1`

Hope this helps and apologies in advance if this needs some fine-tuning!

**Update**

> Do you think the A record can be a wildcard?

There's no problem using wild cards for the DNS subdomains, with an A record pointing
*.example.com ==> Your IP

I think the challenge will be using wildcards in your page rules to automatically forward
userx.example.com/y ==> example.com/files/userx/y

I'm not sure how you could do this using just CloudFlare page rules.

Comment: Thanks for the help David!  Do you think the A record can be a wildcard? Cause user1 could be unlimited i.e. user1,user2,user3... hopefully millions ;-)

Comment: CF does support wildcards in DNS, though I believe it means that you loose some CDN performance and security  features, please see https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168826

Comment: Thanks David... I'm going to spend a bit of time looking into this over the weekend, and get back to you later to let you know how it worked.

Comment: It doesn't seem like Cloudflare allow wildcard forwarding on their free plan... I think they only allow it on their Enterprise plan, which is way too rich for my blood at this time ;-)

Comment: Yes, I thought that wildcard page rules might be a problem. Maybe you could get your idea to work by using CF wildcard for A records to point to your your IP, manually add the subdomain at your server level, then use htaccess to redirect http://userx.example.com to http://example.com/files/userx . Good luck!

Comment: Thanks David... Also, another issues is that it currently needs the last backslash to work i.e. example.com/files/user1/ and won't work if the last backslash is omitted. Is there a way to have it work either way? Or without the last backslash?

Comment: I'm not sure what could be causing your backslash problem ... the first place I would look is your server configuration though